# Ubuntu 20.04 show messy video output through onboard nVidia VGA

Tags: nvidia, graphics, 20.04, gpu-driver, vga

I have an old (2010) Intel Core 2 Duo PC with onboard VGA of nVidia GeForce 7100/ nForce 630i. Recently I install Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and it displaying messy video output.
[image]
I had some graphics issues with 18.04 and 16.04 as well, but 20.04 is unworkable. I tried nVidia driver updates, disabling propitiatory driver and so many other solutions mentioned online, but none of them work for me.

If I'm going to buy used VGA to fix this, what type is better support for Linux

Comment: Regarding your question of which kind of graphics cards work well in Linux: fairly modern AMD cards (e.g. RX series) seem to be working very very well as of late. AMD contributes to the open source driver for them, so it's the best of both worlds: an open source driver that works out of the box, and also contains many optimizations typically only found in proprietary drivers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dedicated VGA card fix this issue without a hassle. In my case **proprietary** driver from graphics card vendor work really good, if you buying a used graphics cards to fix this sort of issue, make sure to buy one manufactured after **2012** it will reduce drivers compatible issues.

[image]